# Append select from database using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

Help me ! 
This code

```js
$(".pro").append("<select name='pro_name'><option value='9'>Laptop</option></select>");
```

is working, but when I'm writing this, it's not working

```js
$(".pro").append("<select name='pro_name'>
      <?php while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query)){?>
      <option value='<?php echo $data['id']; ?>'><?php echo $data['product_name']; ?>  </option>
      <?php } ?>
      </select>");
```

it doesn't show append

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
  $(".pro").append("<select name='pro_name'>
  <?php while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>
   <option value='<?php echo $data['id']; ?>'>
     <?php echo $data['product_name'];?>    
   </option>
  <?php } ?>
  </select>");
```

Warning

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.